# How to create a self-signed certificate for a domain name for development

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have `subdomain.example.com` that I use for development purposes. My web application solution contains a web API etc, that I need to call from external systems, hence I am not using localhost.

I now need to test for SSL and need a certificate for my `subdomain.example.com` development domain name.

I have tried creating a self-signed certificate as outlined in *[Create a Self-Signed Server Certificate in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx)*, but this certificate only works locally. Can this certificate be used for my purpose or will I have to create a self-signed certificate for my development subdomain?

Comment: described process for win/osx here https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-create-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: change subject of question to WINDOWS, and tags please.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

With IIS's self-signed certificate feature, you cannot set the common name (CN) for the certificate, and therefore cannot create a certificate bound to your choice of subdomain.

One way around the problem is to use makecert.exe, which is bundled with the .Net 2.0 SDK. On my server it's at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.Net\SDK\v2.0 64bit\Bin\makecert.exe
```

You can create a signing authority and store it in the LocalMachine certificates repository as follows (these commands must be run from an Administrator account or within an elevated command prompt):

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=My Company Development Root CA,O=My Company,
 OU=Development,L=Wallkill,S=NY,C=US" -pe -ss Root -sr LocalMachine
 -sky exchange -m 120 -a sha1 -len 2048 -r
```

You can then create a certificate bound to your subdomain and signed by your new authority:

(Note that the the value of the -in parameter must be the same as the CN value used to generate your authority above.)

```
makecert.exe -n "CN=subdomain.example.com" -pe -ss My -sr LocalMachine
 -sky exchange -m 120 -in "My Company Development Root CA" -is Root
 -ir LocalMachine -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

Your certificate should then appear in IIS Manager to be bound to your site as explained in Tom Hall's post.

All kudos for this solution to Mike O'Brien for his excellent blog post at http://www.mikeobrien.net/blog/creating-self-signed-wildcard

Comment: I was able to make this work. I had to use the Visual Studio 2010 command prompt for `makecert.exe` to be in my path. For the certificates I thought I'd be more secure and use `-a SHA512 -len 8192` -- it took forever to generate. And as I suspected it might, it had zero impact on what level of encryption IIS used. By default IIS uses 128-bit, you have to do [group policy stuff](http://this-world-is.boldlygoingnowhere.org/andinet/wordpress/index.php/2013/08/256-bit-ssl-with-iis7/) to change this. Of further note to other readers: don't change the magic numbers after `-eku`, they're required.

Comment: The larger bit size governs the symmetric key exchange encryption, not the stream encryption. SSL only uses public key (asymmetric) encryption to securely deliver a symmetric encryption key (the 128bit one).

Comment: Run all above commands from a command prompt with administrative privileges otherwise you'll get an "Error: Save encoded certificate to store failed => 0x5" message.

Comment: I would also like to share a great link [Creating self signed certificates with makecert.exe for development](http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/). The link explain step-by-step approach to creating root certificate, server certificate and client certificate. Plus there is post for explaining how to use them.

Comment: Browsers like Chrome have started to deprecate `sha1`. Substitute `-a sha512` and consider adding `-len 2048` to the second `makecert` invocation and all should be well.

Comment: `makecert` has been deprecated https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate

Comment: Note that this no longer appears to work (at least as shown above) in Windows 10.  I had to use the PowerShell cmdlet instead, which worked without any issue.

Answer (score 149):

**Using PowerShell**

From Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (Windows PowerShell 4.0) and upwards, you can create a self-signed certificate using the new `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet:

Examples:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.mydomain.example -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName subdomain.mydomain.example -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My

New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName *.mydomain.example -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

**Using the IIS Manager**

<sup>Note that IIS certificates use SHA-1 hashing, which isn't supported by modern browsers. IIS cannot create certificates using SHA-2 hashing options, thus it cannot create SSL certificates accepted by modern browsers.</sup>

1. Launch the IIS Manager
2. At the server level, under IIS, select Server Certificates
3. On the right hand side under Actions select Create Self-Signed Certificate
4. Where it says "Specify a friendly name for the certificate" type in an appropriate name for reference.

   - Examples: `www.domain.example` or `subdomain.domain.example`
5. Then, select your website from the list on the left hand side
6. On the right hand side under Actions select Bindings
7. Add a new HTTPS binding and select the certificate you just created (if your certificate is a wildcard certificate you'll need to specify a hostname)
8. Click OK and test it out.

Comment: +1 for the PowerShell solution. Quick and easy, and after doing that, the new cert showed up in my IIS Manager > Connections > Sites > [My Application] > Edit Bindings > Edit > SSL Certificate dropdown.

Comment: I also had to add the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store on Windows 8.1. I followed these directions: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN156440/EN

Comment: @Redtopia Interesting. Did you do that so that browsers would permanently accept your self-signed cert without issuing a warning or because it didn't show up in IIS?

Comment: @TomHall - so that browsers would recognize it as a trusted certificate.

Comment: Having followed the above instructions, & then viewed the certificate, the instructions didnt populate the CN field which still had to the localhost name.

Comment: Exactly. This is wrong! "Friendly name" has nothing to do with CN. I don't know why this answer has so many upvotes?

Comment: This gets upvotes because the Powershell method is indeed working. (See @DivineOps answer) Here is the command I used: `New-SelfSignedCertificate -FriendlyName *.mydomain.local -DnsName *.mydomain.local, localhost -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My` This creates a cert in the Personal store. Then, I first exported the cert to a file and then re-imported it to both IIS via IIS Manager (to use it for my https binding) and then to Trusted Root CAs via MMC (to avoid browser warnings).

Comment: The `-NotAfter` option is also handy to specify an expiration date (without it, the default is just 1 year).  Example I used `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName *.mydomain.com -FriendlyName *.mydomain.com -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(15) -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My`

Comment: Power Shell method is the best one IMO. Simple and easy one. Just one more thing, After successful certificate creation, you have to export it and install it to trusted root(I created one with wildcard cname in my local machine store and installed it in the trusted root of the local machine)

Comment: On Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, the `-FriendlyName` and `-NotAfter` parameters are not recognized, so had to leave them out.  You can assign it a friendly name afterwards via MMC -> Certificates

Comment: Powershell needs to run as administrator.

Comment: IIS Self signed certificate seems not working with Chrome Browser. Use PowerShell option.

Comment: As on today chrome will not accept self-signed certificate generated from IIS Manager. It gives NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID and will not allow to open the website on https.

Answer (score 80):

I had to puzzle my way through self-signed certificates on Windows by combining bits and pieces from the given answers and further resources. Here is my own (and hopefully complete) walk-through. Hope it will spare you some of my own painful learning curve. It also contains infos on related topics that will pop up sooner or later when you create your own certs.

### Create a self-signed certificate on Windows 10 and below

Don't use makecert.exe. It has been deprecated by Microsoft.
The modern way uses a Powershell command.

**Windows 10:**

Open Powershell with Administrator privileges:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate  -DnsName "*.dev.local", "dev.local", "localhost"  -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My  -FriendlyName "Dev Cert *.dev.local, dev.local, localhost"  -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(15)
```

**Windows 8, Windows Server 2012 R2:**

In Powershell on these systems the parameters -FriendlyName and -NotAfter do not exist. Simply remove them from the above command line.
Open Powershell with Administrator privileges:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate  -DnsName "*.dev.local", "dev.local", "localhost"  -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

An alternative is to use the method for older Windows version below, which allows you to use all the features of Win 10 for cert creation...

**Older Windows versions:**

My recommendation for older Windows versions is to create the cert on a Win 10 machine, export it to a .PFX file using an mmc instance (see "Trust the certificate" below) and import it into the cert store on the target machine with the old Windows OS. To import the cert do NOT right-click it. Although there is an "Import certificate" item in the context menu, it failed all my trials to use it on Win Server 2008. Instead open another mmc instance on the target machine, navigate to "Certificates (Local Computer) / Personal / Certificates", right click into the middle pane and select All tasks → Import.

### The resulting certificate

Both of the above commands create a certificate for the domains `localhost` and `*.dev.local`.
The Win10 version additionally has a live time of 15 years and a readable display name of "Dev Cert *.dev.local, dev.local, localhost".

**Update:** If you provide multiple hostname entries in parameter `-DnsName` (as shown above) the first of these entries will become the domain's Subject (AKA Common Name). The complete list of all hostname entries will be stored in the field Subject Alternative Name (SAN) of the certificate. (Thanks to @BenSewards for pointing that out.)

After creation the cert will be immediately available in any HTTPS bindings of IIS (instructions below).

### Trust the certificate (on the machine where you created it)

The new cert is **not** part of any chain of trust and is thus not considered trustworthy by any browsers. To change that, we will copy the cert to the certificate store for Trusted Root CAs on your machine:

Open mmc.exe, File → Add/Remove Snap-In → choose "Certificates" in left column → Add → choose "Computer Account" → Next → "Local Computer..." → Finish → OK

In the left column choose "Certificates (Local Computer) / Personal / Certificates".
Find the newly created cert (in Win 10 the column "Friendly name" may help).
Select this cert and hit Ctrl-C to copy it to clipboard.

In the left column choose "Certificates (Local Computer) / Trusted Root CAs / Certificates".
Hit Ctrl-V to paste your certificate to this store.
The certificate should appear in the list of Trusted Root Authorities and is now considered trustworthy.

### Trust the certificate (on a different machine)

To trust the same cert on a different machine you have to export it on the machine where you created it and import it on the other machine.

On the source machine in MMC right-click the cert → All tasks → Export. Export without(!) private key to .DER format.

Then copy the resulting file to the target machine, right-click and install the cert into the store "Local Computer / Trusted Root CAs". After that all applications that use the windows cert store (i.e. Chrome and IE but NOT Firefox) should trust your self-signed certificate.

### Use in IIS

(We are back on the machine, where you **created** the new certificate!)

Now you may go to IIS Manager, select the bindings of a local website → Add → https → enter a host name of the form  `myname.dev.local` (your cert is only valid for `*.dev.local`) and select the new certificate → OK.

**Add to hosts**

Also add your host name to  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1  myname.dev.local
```

**Happy**

Now Chrome and IE should treat the certificate as trustworthy and load your website when you open up `https://myname.dev.local`.

Firefox maintains its own certificate store. To add your cert here, you must open your website in FF and add it to the exceptions when FF warns you about the certificate.

For Edge browser there may be more action needed (see further down).

### Test the certificate

To test your certs, Firefox is your best choice. (Believe me, I'm a Chrome fan-boy myself, but FF is better in this case.)

Here are the reasons:

- Firefox uses its own SSL cache, which is purged on shift-reload. So any changes to the certs of your local websites will reflect immediately in the warnings of FF, while other browsers may need a restart or a manual purging of the windows SSL cache.
- Also FF gives you some valuable hints to check the validity of your certificate: Click on Advanced when FF shows its certificate warning. FF will show you a short text block with one or more possible warnings in the central lines of the text block:

> The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.

This warning is correct! As noted above, Firefox does not use the Windows certificate store and will only trust this certificate, if you add an exception for it right within Firefox. The button to do this is right below the warnings.

> The certificate is not valid for the name ...

This warning shows, that you did something wrong. The (wildcard) domain of your certificate does not match the domain of your website. The problem must be solved by either changing your website's (sub-)domain or by issuing a new certificate that matches. In fact you could add an exception in FF even if the cert does not match, but you would never get a green padlock symbol in Chrome with such a combination.

Firefox can display many other nice and understandable cert warnings at this place, like expired certs, certs with outdated signing algorithms, etc. I found no other browser that gave me that level of feedback to nail down any problems.

### Which (sub-)domain pattern should I choose to develop?

In the above New-SelfSignedCertificate command we used the wildcard domain `*.dev.local`.

You may think: Why not use `*.local`?

Simple reason: It is illegal as a wildcard domain.
Wildcard certificates *must* contain at least a literal second level domain name. The asterisk (*) is allowed only from the third level upwards.

So, domains of the form `xyz.local` are ok when you develop under HTTP and you don't need certs. But if you use that domain pattern with HTTPS you would be forced to issue a new matching certificate for each new project that you start. Better use domains of the form `xyz.dev.local` and a single wildcard cert for `*.dev.local`.

**Important side notes:**

- Valid host domains may ONLY contain letters a through z, digits, hyphens and dots. No underscores allowed! Some browsers are really picky about this detail and can give you a hard time when they stubbornly refuse to match your domain `motör_head.dev.local` to your wildcard pattern `*.dev.local`. They will comply when you switch to `motoer-head.dev.local`.
- A wildcard in a certificate will only match ONE label (= section between two dots) in a domain, never more. `*.dev.local`  matches  `myname.dev.local`  but NOT `other.myname.dev.local`!
- Multi level wildcards (`*.*.dev.local`) are NOT possible in certificates.
  So `other.myname.dev.local` can only be covered by a wildcard of the form `*.myname.dev.local`. As a result, it is best not to use a forth level domain part. Put all your variations into the third level part. This way you will get along with a single certificate for all your dev sites.

### The problem with Edge

(This is about the old MS Edge version – non-Chromium. I don't think this still applies to the new Chromium version. But I'm not sure.)

This is not really about self-signed certificates, but still related to the whole process:
After following the above steps, Edge may not show *any* content when you open up `myname.dev.local`.
The reason is a characteristic feature of the network management of Windows 10 for Modern Apps, called "Network Isolation".

To solve that problem, open a command prompt with Administrator privileges and enter the following command once:

```
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

More infos about Edge and Network Isolation can be found here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msgulfcommunity/2015/07/01/how-to-debug-localhost-on-microsoft-edge/

Comment: I'd like to note here that the first DNS name is also saved as the Subject Name, which you may not want to be the wild card.

Comment: @BenSewards: Thanks for pointing that out, Ben. I have updated the answer to include the subject / SAN field details. Do you see any problems in having a wildcard hostname in the Subject field instead of the SAN field?

Comment: @Jpsy - This works for me locally on the server where the self-signed cert was created, but not within Firefox or Chrome on my (client) machines. I get `appname.dev has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.` which, as it states, doesn't allow you to add the client exception, contrary to your instruction. Is this a bad configuration within IIS itself with respect to SSL Settings, Require SSL, and the Client certificates options?

Comment: @CodeMaverick: Could there be some ad blocker or anti virus software involved in your problem by any chance? Another option could be that the cert does not match the domain name you use. Remember that the * in the cert's CN or SAN may only represent *one* segment in the domain name (*not* containing any dots). So the CN `*.mydomain.com` can be a valid cert for `me.mydomain.com` but not for `me.at.mydomain.com`.

Comment: This solution works.  One thing to add.  When I try to go to the site first time, it failed with the error message DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.  Run "ipconfig renew", and then ping again.

Comment: Note: If you are required to specify other fields such as organization, you can do so in the subject parameter.  If you use the subject parameter, you should specify CN there as it won't be taken from -DnsName  when -Subject is included:
`-Subject "CN=dev.local,O=CompanyName, OU=IT, L=Boston, S=Massachusetts, C=US"`

Answer (score 67):

**To Create the new certificate for your specific domain:**

Open PowerShell ISE as admin, run the command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName *.mydomain.example, localhost -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

**To trust the new certificate:**

- Open `mmc.exe`
- Go to Console Root -> Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal
- Select the certificate you have created, do right click -> All Tasks -> Export and follow the export wizard to create a .pfx file
- Go to Console Root -> Certificates -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities and import the new .pfx file

**To bind the certificate to your site:**

- Open IIS Manager
- Select your site and choose Edit Site -> Bindings in the right pane
- Add new HTTPS binding with the correct hostname and the new certificate

Comment: This only works in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 (Windows PowerShell 4.0) or later, although you can generate the certificate in one of these OSes and import it later to another computer (I've just done so to use this certificate with SSRS installed in Windows Server 2008 R2).

Comment: Instead of Export & Import to copy it into Trusted Root Certification Authorities, you can just Copy & Paste

Comment: Copy/Paste only works on the same server. You can also ctrl-drag the cert from the Personal folder to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities on the same server. If you want another host to be able to access the site without warnings, then you'll need to export it and have them import the cert into their local TRCA ( you do not need to include the private key).

Comment: you forgot the second step, after opening mmc.exe. Click File, and then click Add/Remove Snap-in, certificate:

Answer (score 20):

I ran into this same problem when I wanted to enable SSL to a project hosted on IIS 8. I post a detailed article in my blog [here](https://runtimecorner.blogspot.com/2021/09/generate-self-signed-certificate-with.html?m=1), but I don't wanna give you a link answer. Finally the tool I used was [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/), after many days fighting with **makecert** commands.The certificate is generated in Debian, but I could import it seamlessly into IIS 7 and 8.

Download the [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) compatible with your OS and [this](https://gist.github.com/josephrodriguez/e3f32f01a46edca6f4e34cd5bcb300b2) configuration file. Set the configuration file as default configuration of OpenSSL.

*First we will generate the private key and certificate of Certification Authority (CA). This certificate is to sign the certificate request (CSR).*

You must complete all fields that are required in this process.

1. `openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -extensions v3_ca -keyout root-cakey.pem -out root-cacert.pem -newkey rsa:4096`

You can create a configuration file with default settings like this:
Now we will generate the certificate request, which is the file that is sent to the Certification Authorities.

**The Common Name must be set the domain of your site, for example:** *public.organization.com*.

2. `openssl req -new -nodes -out server-csr.pem -keyout server-key.pem -newkey rsa:4096`

*Now the certificate request is signed with the generated CA certificate.*

3. `openssl x509 -req -days 365 -CA root-cacert.pem -CAkey root-cakey.pem -CAcreateserial -in server-csr.pem -out server-cert.pem`

The generated certificate must be exported to a .pfx file that can be imported into the IIS.

4. `openssl pkcs12 -export -out server-cert.pfx -inkey server-key.pem -in server-cert.pem -certfile root-cacert.pem -name "Self Signed Server Certificate"`

In this step we will import the certificate CA.

5. In your server must import the CA certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities, for IIS can trust the certificate to be imported. Remember that the certificate to be imported into the IIS, has been signed with the certificate of the CA.

- Open Command Prompt and type **mmc**.
- Click on **File**.
- Select **Add/Remove Snap in...**.
- Double click on **Certificates**.
- Select **Computer Account** and **Next ->**.
- Select **Local Computer** and **Finish**.
- **Ok**.
- Go to **Certificates** -> **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** -> **Certificates**, rigth click on **Certificates** and select **All Tasks** -> **Import** ...

[image]

- Select **Next** -> **Browse ...**
- You must select **All Files** to browse the location of **root-cacert.pem** file.
- Click on **Next** and select **Place all certificates in the following store**: *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*.
- Click on **Next** and **Finish**.

[image]

With this step, the IIS trust on the authenticity of our certificate.

6. In our last step we will import the certificate to IIS and add the binding site.

- Open **Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager** or type *inetmgr* on command prompt and go to **Server Certificates**.
- Click on **Import...**.
- Set the path of .pfx file, the passphrase and Select certificate store on **Web Hosting**.

[image]

- Click on **OK**.
- Now go to your site on IIS Manager and select **Bindings...** and **Add** a new binding.
- Select https as the type of binding and you should be able to see the imported certificate.
- Click on **OK** and all is done.

[image]

Comment: I wanted to have longer expiration with a self signed certificate and Windows SDK with makecert.exe was not available on the Windows host. A Linux host and this answer provided the solution.

Comment: I'm glad that you found useful my answer.

Comment: Where to put that "public.organization.com" into openssl command?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create a self-signed certificate that allows you to specify the domain name per website. This means you can use it across many domain names.

In IIS Manager

1. Click machine name node
2. Open Server Certificates
3. In Actions panel, choose 'Create Self-Signed Certificate'
4. In 'Specify a friendly name...' name it *Dev (select 'Personal' from type list)
5. Save

Now, on your website in IIS...

1. Manage the bindings
2. Create a new binding for Https
3. Choose your self-signed certificate from the list
4. Once selected, the domain name box will become enabled and you'll be able to input your domain name.

[image]

Comment: Thanks the most useful answer so far. At least to use it on development this is fast.