# How to wire up a valid local self-signed certificate for ASP.NET Core and IIS 10 on Windows 10?

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, iis

We're not using Kestrel, nor IIS Express. We use IIS for local development. Thus we can't find out any command of `dotnet dev-certs` to help us.

We can create a self-signed certificate in IIS by going into server node, then Server Certificates, then Create a self-signed certificate, and give it a name and either Personal or Web Hosting, and it's created. Then use it in binding of our site (443, https, choosing certificate and `domain.local`)

However, when we want to go to `domain.local` in Google Chrome we get that untrusted certificate warning.

We can export certificate in IIS and double click it to install it in Windows. Now the error we see in Chrome is that this certificate is created for `LocalComputerName` and can't be used for `domain.local`.

At this point we're stuck at how to specify domains (Subject Alternative Names or SAN) for self-signed certificates, and how to automate this process from command line.

Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a self-signed certificate for a domain name for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441155/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-for-a-domain-name-for-development)